# What is the heaviest aircraft fitted with a central control stick?

Tags: flight-controls

Primary control surfaces for roll and pitch are controlled either by a wheel (C-172, Concorde, ...) or by a center-stick (mirage 2000, most gliders, ...). Wheel tend to be used for bigger aircraft. E.g. I don't know any airliner fitted with a center stick.

What is the biggest aircraft (highest MTOW) fitted with a center-stick? (Airbus style side-stick are excluded.)

Comment: You have for some reason omitted sidesticks from the (original) first paragraph of you question. They are a very common control interface, therefore you cannot just say *...roll and pitch are controlled either by a wheel or by a center stick.*

Comment: When you exclude Airbus-style, do you mean FBW is not permitted? Or is it just the location of the stick that matters?

Comment: @ymb1 i was first thinking of joystick, but given my initial wording and the fact that an answer already exists I think the location matters more (i.e. space shuttle's input are not excluded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest I can find is at [585,000 lb](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/1529726/c-17-globemaster-iii/) the [C-17 has a center stick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SU9oVEuNJvY) but depending on what you mean by "airbus style" this may be disqualified.

Other contenders:

- The SR-71 had a MTOW of 172,000 lb and had a center stick
- <strike>If you consider the time it spent in the atmosphere as qualifications for "aircraft" at 240,000 lb [the Space Shuttle had a center stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_orbiter)</strike>

Comment: By biggest, I mean highest MTOW. For the space shuttle such value is irrelevant as she doesn't take off from a runway.

Comment: @ManuH i have updated to reflect, i left the shuttle MTOW since it is an officially listed value but your point is noted.